# How to get images path from project resource folder and send to another class in java eclipse

Tags: java

In my Java web application, I need to access the path from my project resources inside images and send it to another `sendmail.java` class how can i take images path from resource folder can anyone please tell me

my image folder:

[image folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPR0p.png)

when i tried with the below code it shows `file not found error`

I tried with this:

```
String imgpath="/resources/HappyBirthday.JPG";
SendEmail stp=new SendEmail();
stp.mail(From, To,Name,text,imgpath);
```

SendEmail.java:

```
public String mail(String From,String To,String Name,String text,String imgPath){
Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.com");
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
          // Get the default Session object.
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
 try {            
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(From));
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(To));
             message.setSubject("Wishes!", "UTF-8");
             message.setText(text, "UTF-8");

          // first part (the html)
              BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
              String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
              messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
              // add it

            // second part (the image)
              messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();         
              DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(imgPath); //here adding image path to send mail like image and text 
              messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
              messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");           
             MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
             message.setContent(multipart);
             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");          
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println(mex);
          }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `"/HappyBirthday.JPG"`?

Comment: HI,@SilverNak, I tried with your code it shows same exception `javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: \HappyBirthday.JPG (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: Then you have to read it via classloader. Check @StanislavL s answer

Answer (score 1):

It iis not correct to expect file. If your code is compiled in a jar the file is not available.

Instead use

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/HappyBirthday.JPG");

ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream, "image/jpg");
```

When the code is compiled resources are moved to `classes` and can be accessed there as resources streams not files.

Comment: HI,@StanislavL, how can i send it into another class could you please tell me

Comment: Hi,@StanislavL,when i used your code i got this exception An exception has occuredjava.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream  but i am using `import java.io.InputStream` this one only

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, you should add this to your pom.xml

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

And then it will work with just

```
String imgpath="HappyBirthday.JPG";
```

I'm sorry if I'm wrong about Maven, I still cannot comment on questions

Comment: I am not using Maven